# users.models.Profile.user.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: Profile has no user

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I am designing a website to take in and store a users information under a profile. The main issue I am running into seems to be between the profile and user relationship. When I try and delete empty profiles from the admin page it gives me this error:

```
(py3) (base) Ethans-MBP-2:opinions_app ethanjay$ python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
March 05, 2020 - 00:09:33
Django version 2.2.10, using settings 'django_project.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[05/Mar/2020 00:09:42] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3142
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[05/Mar/2020 00:09:42] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 4608
[05/Mar/2020 00:09:46] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 8342
[05/Mar/2020 00:09:47] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 8342
[05/Mar/2020 00:09:50] "GET /admin/users/profile/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6300
[05/Mar/2020 00:09:50] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3223
Internal Server Error: /admin/users/profile/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ethanjay/Enviroments/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/ethanjay/Enviroments/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/ethanjay/Enviroments/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/ethanjay/Enviroments/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 606, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ethanjay/Enviroments/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ethanjay/Enviroments/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ethanjay/Enviroments/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 223, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ethanjay/Enviroments/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 45, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ethanjay/Enviroments/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ethanjay/Enviroments/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1711, in changelist_view
    response = self.response_action(request, queryset=cl.get_queryset(request))
  File "/Users/ethanjay/Enviroments/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1397, in response_action
    response = func(self, request, queryset)
  File "/Users/ethanjay/Enviroments/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/actions.py", line 28, in delete_selected
    deletable_objects, model_count, perms_needed, protected = modeladmin.get_deleted_objects(queryset, request)
  File "/Users/ethanjay/Enviroments/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1833, in get_deleted_objects
    return get_deleted_objects(objs, request, self.admin_site)
  File "/Users/ethanjay/Enviroments/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/utils.py", line 151, in get_deleted_objects
    to_delete = collector.nested(format_callback)
  File "/Users/ethanjay/Enviroments/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/utils.py", line 211, in nested
    roots.extend(self._nested(root, seen, format_callback))
  File "/Users/ethanjay/Enviroments/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/utils.py", line 197, in _nested
    ret = [format_callback(obj)]
  File "/Users/ethanjay/Enviroments/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/utils.py", line 126, in format_callback
    no_edit_link = '%s: %s' % (capfirst(opts.verbose_name), obj)
  File "/Users/ethanjay/Django Projects/opinions_app/users/models.py", line 52, in __str__
    if self.user:
  File "/Users/ethanjay/Enviroments/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 189, in __get__
    "%s has no %s." % (self.field.model.__name__, self.field.name)
users.models.Profile.user.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: Profile has no user.
```

Below I included any files I thought might be important. Any advice or pointers to get me going in the right direction are greatly appreciated.

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    GENS = (('m','Male'),('f','Female'),('o','Not Represented Above'))
    RACES = (('ai','American Indian or Alaska Native'),('as','Asian'),('bl','Black or African American'),('hi','Hispanic or Latino'),('ha','Native Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander'),('wh','White'))
    ETHNICITIES = (('n','Not Hispanic or Latino'),('h','Hispanic or Latino'))
    INCBRACKET = (('a','$0 - $10,000'),('b','$10,001 - $40,000'),('c','$40,001 - $80,000'),('d','$80,001 - $150,000'),('e','$150,001 - $250,000'),('e','$250,001 - $500,000'),('e','$500,000+'))
    EDUCATION = (('NE','No Formal Education'),('HS','High School Diploma'),('AD','Associate Degree'),('BD','Bachelor\'s Degree'),('MD','Masters\'s Degree'),('DD','Doctorate'))
    EMPLOYMENT = (('e','Currently Employed'),('u','Currently Unemployed'))

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    gender = models.CharField(max_length = 1, choices = GENS, default = '')
    birthday = models.DateField(default = '1900-01-01')
    address = models.OneToOneField(Address, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null = True)
    race = models.CharField(max_length = 2, choices = RACES, default = 'x')
    ethnicity = models.CharField(max_length = 1, choices = ETHNICITIES, default = 'x')
    income = models.CharField(max_length = 1, choices = INCBRACKET, default = 'x')
    education = models.CharField(max_length = 2, choices = EDUCATION, default = 'x')
    employment = models.CharField(max_length = 1, choices = EMPLOYMENT, default = 'x')

    def post_save_user_model_reciever(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
        if created:
            try:
                Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
            except:
                pass

    def __str__(self):
        if self.user:
            return f'{self.user.username}'
    def save(self, *args, **kawrgs):
        super().save(*args, **kawrgs)
        img = Image.open(self.image.path)
        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import UserRegisterForm, UserUpdateForm, ProfileUpdateForm, PIIForm, FinalPIIForm
from .models import Profile




def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created! You are now able to log in')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})


@login_required
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST,
                                   request.FILES,
                                   instance=request.user.profile)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been updated!')
            return redirect('profile')

    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form
    }
    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)

def PII(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PIIForm(request.POST,)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.user = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
            form.save()
            return redirect('FinalPII')
    else:
        form = PIIForm(request.POST)
    return render(request, 'users/pii.html', {'form':form})

def FinalPII(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FinalPIIForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = FinalPIIForm(request.POST)

    return render(request, 'users/finalpii.html', {'form':form})
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Profile



class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']



class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email']


class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['image']

class PIIForm(forms.ModelForm):
    birthday = forms.DateField()
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = [
        'gender',
        'birthday',
        'race',
        'ethnicity'
        ]

class FinalPIIForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = [
        'income',
        'education',
        'employment',
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing one line of code, post save signals to connect to user model.When user is created an instance of profile also should be created.

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

post_save.connect(post_save_user_model_reciever, sender=User)
```